# Como obtener un array de strings de un json recibido de Node js con angular

Tags: json, array, angular, objeto, autocomplete

trabajo en un AUTOCOMPLETE con Angular 8 y Node Js, recibo este formato json:

```
countries: {};

this.countries =
[{"countryId":1,"countryName":"Afghanistan","countryKey":"AF"},
{"countryId":2,"countryName":"Albania","countryKey":"AL"},
{"countryId":3,"countryName":"Algeria","countryKey":"DZ"}]
```

necesito convertirlo en un array pero obteniendo solo los valores de countryName, de este tipo:

```
["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria"]
```

para poder pasarlos al AUTOCOMPLETE (que al no poder hacerlo funcionar con conexión a MySQL, opté por guardar los datos obtenidos en un array, esperando poder conseguirlo así). Tengo la forma de conseguirlo usando `formControl` pero no puedo hacerlo porque utilizo `[(ngModel)]` que no se pueden combinar a partir de angular7 según tengo entendido.

LAS PREGUNTAS SON:

1. ¿Cómo paso el `countryName` del `json` a un array de strings?
2. ¿Alguien tiene algún ejemplo para un AUTOCOMPLETE que conecte a `MySQL` sin usar `formControl` que pueda facilitar?

MUCHAS GRACIAS.

Comment: Me funcionó con esto:

`options = [];
function(){
   let texto = JSON.stringify(this.countries);
   let info = JSON.parse(texto);
   for (let item of info) {
          this.options.push(item.countryName);
        }
        console.log(this.options);
}`

Respecto al AUTOCOMPLETE... sigo buscando

Answer (score 0):

Para pasar el array con los objetos de cada pais puedes usar la funcion **map** que ya viene incluida con los arrays en javascript te dejo un ejemplo de como hacerlo y ponerlo en una variable llamada **countriesNames**

```
this.countries =
[{"countryId":1,"countryName":"Afghanistan","countryKey":"AF"},
{"countryId":2,"countryName":"Albania","countryKey":"AL"},
{"countryId":3,"countryName":"Algeria","countryKey":"DZ"}]

this.countriesNames = this.countries.map(item => item.countryName)
```

Comment: probé también el **map**, pero me generaba un error del tipo: no soporta el tipo {}.